# NUnit 2.5.7 Breakpoint still not hit (VS2010) even after attaching to the Agent

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, nunit-2.5

I am having a problem hitting the break point in debugging under VS2010 under
NUnit recent recommended release 2.5.7
I have tried various ways as recommended by responses on Stack Overflow:

1. Attach to NUnit-agent.exe
2. Run time is correctly selected to 4.0
3. Attaching to Nunit.exe which does not even debug symbols

When attaching to the nunit-agent.exe, the symbols seem to load; however the
test completes w/o hitting the breakpoint..

Anyone seen this problem??

Comment: Is the breakpoint in your test project or in the project under test? Also, it may help to see the code that contains the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using the right framework version. .Net 4 is too high, so try using .Net 3.5

Also, don't bother with the hassle of attaching to a process. That gets old very quickly. Instead, go to the properties for your unit test project, and and the Debug tab, set "Start external program:" to point to nunit.exe, and add the output dll name in the "Command line arguments" text box (eg UnitTests.dll)

Answer (score 2):

Attach to `nunit-agent.exe`, not just `nunit.exe`. I don't know why but it will cause breakpoints to work